# How do I calculate the strength to weight ratio of this object?

Tags: stresses, strength

I have an object that weighs approximately 10 grams = 0.022 pounds. I know it can hold at least 45.1 pounds without breaking. It's a cube-like object so I placed many books on top of it and weighed the books.

I want to compare the strength of the object to steel to see how strong the object is.

> How do I calculate the strength to weight ratio of this object?

I think it can hold 2,050 times its weight based on 45.1/.022=2,050.

I read that megapascal's (MPa) are used to assess how much force an object can withstand.

A megapascal (MPa) is a metric pressure unit, mostly used in hydraulic systems that gauge high pressure ratings, that equals 1,000,000 newtons per square meter (which is a pascal). 1 MPa is equal to 10 Bar.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you drive a 30 ton truck over a piece of paper, the weight of the truck doesn't "break" the paper. What is the real question you are trying to ask?

Comment: I meant to say "cube"-like object. It's 3 dimensional

Comment: I think this would be a valid question if you rephrased it. Something like "how do I calculate the strength to weight ratio of this object" (along with more details about the object and force applied to it).